# Which WPF template to use?

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate, controltemplate, contenttemplate

I'd like to create a re-usable ListView with rows of any or all of:

Labels + textboxes 
or 
Labels + Comboboxes
or
Labels + DatePickers

using Templates. I still do not understand Templates too well and would like to know which of them - ControlTemplate, DataTemplate, ItemsTemplate or ContentTemplate - to use for this and how. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you create ViewModels for the items in your ListBox, then create DataTemplates for the ViewModels in resources. This is a good place to start reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 different types of templates: `DataTemplate` and `ControlTemplate`. `ControlTemplate` is used on the `Template` property of classes derived from `Control` and defines the visual tree for a specific type of control.

Pretty much any other place that templates show up is using `DataTemplate`. This includes `ContentTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` properties. `DataTemplates` define a visual tree for any non-Visual data type. When the template is rendered its `DataContext` is the data object being rendered (i.e. a `List<T>` item) making it easy to bind data properties.

To mix templates for different types in a single list you can use a `DataTemplateSelector` which allows you to write code to pick a template for each item. The other option is to create multiple implicit templates (`DataType` but no `x:Key`) for the different CLR types of objects in the list. As long as those templates are in the resource scope of the control rendering the collection the types will resolve their templates automatically.

Comment: Hi @JohnBowen, thank you for your answer, greatly appreciate it. Would it be possible for you to post an example each for the 2 approaches? Thanks.

Comment: Found this. Posting it for anyone else interested: http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/361#.VRwJWvnF-p0